# Integrality of the $L$-genus for a smooth manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

For a compact, oriented, smooth manifold $M^{4k}$, the Hirzebruch signature theorem gives the signature $\sigma(M)$ in terms of a polynomial $P_k$ in the Pontryagin numbers of $M$ whose coefficients are rational but have very large denominators. In particular, $P_k$ is integer-valued because $\sigma(M^{4k})$ is. The usual proof (at least the ones I've seen) of the result is to compute $\Omega^{SO}_* \otimes \mathbb{Q}$, note that signature is invariant under (oriented) cobordism, and then show that $P_k$ gives the right result on the generators $\mathbb{CP}^{2m}$. Is there a direct proof, though, or even some sort of reason why the integrality should hold?

To take a more narrow example: In dimension 4, the class $p_1(M^4) = 3\sigma(M) \in 3\mathbb{Z}$ if $M$ is smooth. Is there any other significance to $p_1(M^4)\in \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ beyond just being an obstruction to smoothability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want $M$ to be compact and oriented. Integrality holds because the signature is manifestly integral; the real question is why the signature is given by some particular rational combination of characteristic numbers.

From a modernish point of view results of this form should be thought of as consequences of variations on the [Atiyah-Singer index theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atiyah%E2%80%93Singer_index_theorem), which gives a very general recipe for showing that certain integer-valued invariants (indexes of elliptic operators) can be computed in terms of certain characteristic numbers. Some proofs of the index theorem proceed by using a cobordism argument to reduce the theorem to checking particular cases, but many others don't; there are a startling variety of proofs, really.

One reason things are particularly mysterious without the index theorem is that more sophisticated integrality arguments of this form depend on the manifold having more sophisticated extra structure. From the perspective of index theory the point of this extra structure is to allow you to define extra interesting elliptic operators; otherwise it's pretty unclear what's going on. For example, the A-hat genus is integral on spin manifolds because spin structures let you write down an operator called the Dirac operator whose index is the A-hat genus.

Comment: Thanks, I edit to the original post to emphasize that I was working in the compact, oriented category. (The rational unoriented cobordism ring $\Omega^O_*\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ is not very interesting. I'm actually thinking about closed manifolds specifically, just for simplicity.) I actually am familiar--- or acquainted, at least--- with the Atiyah-Singer index theorem, though for whatever reason I haven't seen a proof of the Hirzebruch signature theorem using it. I've done a bit of work with 4-manifold topology, so I'm familiar with the Dirac operator and the $\hat A$-genus, (continued below)

Comment: and that was part of the motivation for the question: There are some invariants that pop up as smooth obstructions smoothness, like the Rokhlin invariant $\frac{1}{8}\sigma(M^4)$ for a homology $3$-sphere $\delta M$, that look like integrality conditions on various classes. I was wondering more if there's any significance to the bizarre relations like $7p_2 - p_1^2\equiv 0 \pmod{45}$ in dimension $8$; or, instead, if they're just a consequence of the fact that the $\Omega^{SO}_*$ is small and thus cobordism invariants have to satisfy certain linear equations just because of their dimension.

Comment: Er, I 'edited', etc. Typing while eating is not recommended. Also, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Index theory is the only way I know to make sense of any of these integrality conditions. I think there are other ways; e.g. Rokhlin's theorem can be proven using index theory but it can also be proven using a calculation in stable homotopy that I'm not familiar with.